# cannot find element by id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to listen for submit event of form.I have included my js files finely and also written my form element correctly.It keeps on screming

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

My HTML File

```js
/*Form Listener*/
var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', saveBookmark);

function saveBookmark(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('Form Submitted');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bookmark App | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-center">Bookmark App</h2>
            <hr>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h3>Bookmark Your Favorite Sites</h3> <br>
                    <form id="myForm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Website Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Website Name" id="siteName">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Website URL</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Website URL" id="siteUrl">
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: make this line of code to be very last element of your body tag <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: because you are trying to access your element, where it isn't loaded yet

Answer (score 3):

HTML (and JavaScript) run from top to bottom.

Assuming that the JavaScript that you have loaded is in `main.js` then this is loaded and processed before the html containing the element `myForm` has loaded.

Instead, you need to move your reference to `main.js` to the bottom of your html (somewhere below the `</form>` closing tag).